# Stop a timer on an if statement within a view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'am quite new to Swift and I despair of a problem.
I created a class with two functions to start and stop a timer.
There's a struct that starts the timer (start function) with onAppear.
Within the struct there's a button to stop the time.

```
import SwiftUI

class StopWatch: ObservableObject {
    @Published var secondsElapsed = 0.0
    var timer = Timer()
    
    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.secondsElapsed += 0.1 }
    }
    func stopTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}


struct Test: View {
    @ObservedObject var stopWatch = StopWatch()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Stop") {
                stopWatch.stopTimer()
            }
            Text(String(format: "%.1f", self.stopWatch.secondsElapsed))
        }.onAppear(perform: {stopWatch.startTimer()})
    }
}
```

The timer starts if the view starts. So far so good :-).
But I want to get rid of the stop button and replace it with an if statement like:

if stopWatch.secondsElapsed > 5.0 {
stopWatch.stopTimer() }

I want to stop the timer without a user action by this if statement and the current timer value should show up.

I tried for hours, but I didn't get it. For that case I get the error message "*Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'*", but I tried a lot of other things and got a lot of other errors.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can do it inside the closure for the timer work like that should never be in the `body`

Comment: Unrelated but `String(format:` is dated. Today it's simply `Text(stopWatch.secondsElapsed.formatted())`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the timer to stop on 5 seconds you should probably do this in the closure from the timer. You can do this:

```
func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
        self.secondsElapsed += 0.1
        if self.secondselapsed == 5.0 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

You get this error ("Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'") because you try to execute code within the body of a SwiftUI view without returning a view. If you really want to do this in the body for some reason you could do it like this: (I would not recommend doing this)

```
if stopWatch.secondsElapsed > 5.0 {
    Text("Five seconds elapsed")
        .onAppear {
            stopWatch.stop()
        }
}
```